# Send a notification email to administrators when student enrolled for a course

Tags: email, notifications

I have enrollment form for students to enroll for courses in Drupal. Here is the all code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\student_enrollment\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

/**
 * Provides a Student Enrollment form.
 */
class StudentEnrollmentForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'student_enrollment_student_enrollment';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $course_id = NULL) {
    // Build the enrollment form elements here.
    // Add a dropdown for selecting courses.
    $course_name = Node::load($course_id)->label();
    $form['course'] = [
      '#type' => 'label',
      '#title' => $this->t('<h2>Enroll for the ' . $course_name . ' course</h2>'),
    ];
    $form['course_id'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => $course_id
    ];
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Enroll'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Implement validation logic if needed.
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Implement submission logic to record the enrollment in the database.
    $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
    $course_id = $form_state->getValue('course_id');
    // Check if the user is already enrolled in the selected course.
    if (!$this->isUserEnrolled($uid, $course_id)) {
      // Record the enrollment.
      $this->recordEnrollment($uid, $course_id);
      $this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Enrollment successful.'));
      $notification_service = \Drupal::service('student_enrollment.notify_enrollment');
      $notification_service->sendEnrollmentNotification($uid, $course_id);
    } else {
      $this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('You are already enrolled for this course.'), 'warning');
    }
  }

  /**
   * Check if a user is already enrolled in a course.
   *
   * @param int $uid
   *   The user ID.
   * @param int $course_id
   *   The course ID.
   *
   * @return bool
   *   TRUE if the user is already enrolled, FALSE otherwise.
   */
  private function isUserEnrolled($uid, $course_id) {
    // Implement logic to check if the user is already enrolled in the course.
    // This is a placeholder; replace it with your actual implementation.

    $query = \Drupal::database()->select('student_enrollments', 'e');
    $query->fields('e');
    $query->condition('user_id', $uid);
    $query->condition('course_id', $course_id);
    $result = $query->execute();

    return !empty($result->fetchAssoc());
  }

  /**
   * Record a user's enrollment in a course.
   *
   * @param int $uid
   *   The user ID.
   * @param int $course_id
   *   The course ID.
   */
  private function recordEnrollment($uid, $course_id) {
    // Implement logic to record the user's enrollment in the database.
    // This is a placeholder; replace it with your actual implementation.
    \Drupal::database()->insert('student_enrollments')
      ->fields([
        'user_id' => $uid,
        'course_id' => $course_id,
        'created' => date('Y/M/d H:i:s',\Drupal::time()->getRequestTime())
      ])
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

When i submit the form (successfully enrolled for a course) i called method from a custom service that sends emails to administrators to notify them that a given student has enrolled for a course. Here is the service class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\student_enrollment\Service;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;

/**
 * Service description.
 */
class EnrollmentNotificationService {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  protected $configFactory;

  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $configFactory) {
    $this->configFactory = $configFactory;
  }

  public function sendEnrollmentNotification($user, $course) {
    $notificationEmails = $this->configFactory->get('enrollment_management.settings')->get('notification_emails');
    $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
    $module = 'enrollment_management';
    $key = 'enrollment_notification';
    $to = $notificationEmails;
    $params = [
      'user' => $user,
      'course' => $course,
    ];
    $languageManager =  \Drupal::languageManager()
    ->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)
    ->getId();
    $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $languageManager, $params);
  }
}
```

I want to know whether this service is written well for sending emails. I expected when i submit the enrollment form, the email to be sent to administrator to be notified that a student has enrolled for a new course.